# GeocoderTask error

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding

I am trying to follow some projects about geocoder and integrate it into my project.
I am getting a redline under execute in the line  `new GeocoderTask().execute(hosname);` but the existing project that i used as a reference does not contain this kind of error. When i press ctr+1 is shows 3 options: 
 1:Change to on PostExcute 
 2.Change type of hosname to String[] 
3.Create method execute 'Textview' in type Geocoder Task.

 The existing project that i used was using an edit text to get the name of the address to be shown, while my project is referencing it from a textview. What should i do about this?

```
package com.dr.droid.lee;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HospResult extends MapActivity {

    String hcity;
    String hregion;
    String hadd;
    String hname;
    String hcon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"MyriadPro-Bold.ttf");
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        TextView hosname =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView hosreg =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegion);
        TextView hosadd =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
        TextView hoscon =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContact);
        TextView hoscity =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCity);
        Bundle receive = getIntent().getExtras();
        hcity = receive.getString("city");
        hregion = receive.getString("region");
        hadd = receive.getString("address");
        hname = receive.getString("name");
        hcon = receive.getString("contact");
        hosname.setText(hname);
        hosreg.setText(hregion);
        hoscity.setText(hcity);
        hosadd.setText(hcon);
        hoscon.setText(hadd);
        hosname.setTypeface(type);
        hosreg.setTypeface(type);
        hosadd.setTypeface(type);
        hoscity.setTypeface(type);
        hoscon.setTypeface(type);
        MapView mv =  (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mv1);
        MapController mp = mv.getController();
        mp.setZoom(15);
        if(hosname!=null && !hosname.equals("")){
            new GeocoderTask().execute(hosname);
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    // An AsyncTask class for accessing the GeoCoding Web Service
        private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>>{

            @Override
            protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
                // Creating an instance of Geocoder class
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
                List<Address> addresses = null;

                try {
                    // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 3);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }           
                return addresses;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {

                // Getting Reference to MapView of the layout activity_main
                MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mv1);

                // Setting ZoomControls
                mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

                // Getting MapController for the MapView
                MapController mc = mapView.getController();
                mc.setZoom(18);

                // Getting Drawable object corresponding to a resource image
                Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);


                // Getting Overlays of the map
                List<Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();

                // Creating an ItemizedOverlay
                LocationOverlay locationOverlay = new LocationOverlay(drawable,getBaseContext());

                // Clearing the overlays
                overlays.clear();

                if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // Redraws the map to clear the overlays
                    mapView.invalidate();
                }

                // Adding Markers on Google Map for each matching address
                for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){                

                    Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);

                    // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in Google Map
                    GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(
                                              (int)(address.getLatitude()*1E6),
                                              (int)(address.getLongitude()*1E6)
                                             );

                    String addressText = String.format("%s, %s",
                            address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                            address.getCountryName());


                    // Creating an OverlayItem to mark the point
                    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(p, "Location",addressText);

                    // Adding the OverlayItem in the LocationOverlay
                    locationOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);

                    // Adding locationOverlay to the overlay
                    overlays.add(locationOverlay);

                    // Locate the first location
                    if(i==0)
                        mc.animateTo(p);                    
                }

                // Redraws the map
                mapView.invalidate();

            }       
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Type `hosname` is TextView, maybe this cause error?

try execute `new GeocoderTask().execute(hosname.getText());`

Comment: i tried what you suggested sir, but still got a red line. i tried a quick fix it became new GeocoderTask().execute((Runnable) hosname.getText()); but the whole line got a yellow line

Comment: i tried new GeocoderTask().execute(hosname.toString()); the error is gone, gonna try and run this. you post gave me an idea, thanks sir!